# Restart Activity on uncaughtException

Tags: java, android, uncaught-exception

in the onCreate method of an Activity, I'm running this :

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

What I am trying to do is, when in this activity, I would like to restart it and clear previous intents, with these lines of code, I end up having a blank screen and the app running in the background, either way I have to restart it or kill it from the multitasking screen and this is not really user friendly. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit : Is it also possible to build an alert dialog in here as well and display some message? And perhaps on OK press, the redirect will happen

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, this is a temporary solution. I don't understand the downvotes though :) I'm asking about something that's in the API and I would like some info regarding how to use it. I'm not asking for other possible suggestions since I know this is not the best approach

Comment: Meanwhile I will just have you reported for the poor answers and the 0 arguments attached to it :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this did the trick for me :

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

                Intent crashedIntent = new Intent(MainDrawer.this, MainDrawer.class);
                crashedIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                crashedIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(crashedIntent);

                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is this MainDrawer? I tried with my ErrorScreenActivity and I get `error: not an enclosing class: ErrorScreenActivity`